# How to check iPhone connection with USB in Programming?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to know how to check iPhone connection with USB in Programming.
Many case suggest using check Battery status.
but this case fails in case of charging of iPhone using iPhone charger
so...
May I ask alternative way of this case, please?
And
What return value if an iPhone is connected to iPhone charger.

Comment: Are you trying to check the connection status in an iPhone app, or in a desktop program? If desktop, what language? In general, more details would help you get a useful answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer^_^
Language in use C or Object-C. but this case using Object-C.
Actually I want both^_^;;;
I develop in desktop and install iPone.
Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this before, This is a link to a project I built quite some time ago, I just commented stuff out, have a look to get the general idea, this was a side project that I created to kill time, hope you find it useful, please comment here if you have any questions.

https://github.com/MrHaze/USBDetect

I used NSTask to get a command line reading of plugged in items, then used grep to filter out the word "iPad" or "iPhone", you can just run the command and see what you get, and adjust accordingly.

feel free to contribute.

although [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/USBBook/USBDeviceInterfaces/USBDevInterfaces.html) is probably a better way of doing it

If you are trying to find out on the device side, have a look at this [link](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/IOKit.framework) it might help you.

Comment: Oh! thank you! 
I'm start-up IOS Programming.
so...if Using Mac OS's lib in IOS, is it pssible?

Comment: NP :) You can't use NSTask on iOS, you can only find out on your mac. you can also have a look at this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/USBBook/USBDeviceInterfaces/USBDevInterfaces.html

Comment: Oh!
I'm really thank you for your kindness ^_^
Let's start test you suggest and reference your link!
Thank you so much, and Have a nice day~